# jQuery Popup Menu On Page Refresh

Tags: jquery, popup, refresh

I have developed a PopupMenu using a jQuery plugin.

When the HTML button is clicked the PopupMenu should appear.

Is it possible to do this instead when the page refreshes?
How would I do this in jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('area').bind("click",function(e){
        //popupcode
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't that do?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
              $('area').bind("click",function(e){

                      //popupcode
                });
              //popupcode
       });
```

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
$('area').click();
```

to fire the event after the binding :)